# Raspberry to capture cetaceans sounds

Tags: microphone

I am looking to create a raspberry pi able to use a hydrophone such as the [H2d](https://www.audiosense.be/en/aquarian-audio-h2d-xlr-3-aqu-h2dx3-1). I am not sure whether XLR or 3.5mm is better to record cetaceans' sounds.

Does anyone know if the microphone can connect directly to the raspberry or needs an extra component? Moreover, since I am looking at cetaceans, the sounds would fall in the ultrasounds spectrum, is the raspberry able to detect ultrasounds or do I need something more powerful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Can I directly connect a microphone to my raspberry pi?

This all depends on how you want to connect a microphone to your RPI, and what kind of hardware you will use.
For example, I have a microphone connected to a **sound card** (audio interface) via XLR, and the soundcard is connected to my PC via a standard **USB cable**.
As for your microphone, you will need some additional hardware as well (a **preamp**):

> The H2d-XLR can be used with any microphone preamp with mating
> connector and phantom power.

As long as you find an interface that works with raspberry pi (look for available drivers), and a preamp for your microphone, you should be good to go.

### Should I use 3.5mm or XLR?

Always connect the microphone to the preamp/interface with **XLR cables** for maximum quality. It doesn't matter what kind of audio you're recording.

### Is the raspberry able to detect ultrasounds or do I need something more powerful?

This falls within the realm of the microphone itself. It has nothing to do with raspberry pi.